# Correct way to call a piece of code only available in the next standard version

Tags: c++, gcc

I have a gcc 13.1 and I cannot use std c++23.

I need to use chunk algorithm implemented in gcc 13.1 std c++23.

How can I do to call `std::views::chunck` with importing source code from 13.1/master branch of gcc.

Comment: You cannot. Sometimes libraries are available with exeperimental implementations. I did not check extensively but it seems to be have an implementation here : https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3/blob/master/test/view/chunk.cpp

Comment: "_I have a gcc 13.1 and I cannot use std c++23._": What does "cannot" mean? If you have a compiler version supporting the feature you want, then what is stopping you from setting `-std=c++23`? If you want to use a C++23 then setting that flag is what is telling the compiler to make it available to you. Because this is a C++23 feature, the standard library implementation might not even be compatible with C++20 or earlier.

Comment: @PepijnKramer, range-v3 is not fully compatible with standard. example chunk cannot by use with iota

Comment: @user17732522, external dependencies oblige me to not use c++23

Comment: how about using `range-v3` ? whatever you are trying to do has no "correct way", everything in it depends on the current implementation details of a certain version of the compiler, the only reliable way is to use `-std=c++23`

Comment: @AhmedAEK, Okay, I will try range-v3